# Get YUV420 bytes from JCodec Picture

Tags: java, h.264, jcodec

Using an H264Decoder I would like to obtain the decoded YUV420 data as a Java byte array. I have searched all over and I don't see any examples that fit.

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(h264EncodedByteArray);
H264Decoder decoder = new H264Decoder();
// assume that sps and pps are set on the decoder
Picture out = Picture.create(320, 240, ColorSpace.YUV420); 
Picture real = decoder.decodeFrame(buf, out.getData());
```

The "h264EncodedByteArray" would be an array of h264 encoded bytes from a stream or file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the buf and avcC box must be supplied when doing the decode. Before any decoding can commence, you must provide avcC data.

```
AvcCBox avcCBox = new AvcCBox();
avcCBox.parse(buf);
```

After the avcC is created, you can use the following line to get the Picture.

```
decoder.decodeFrame(H264Utils.splitMOVPacket(buf, avcCBox), out.getData());
```

In the code above the buf may or may not contain multiple NAL elements.